# Bitbucket: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python-3.x, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to setup unit tests in Bitbucket using the following `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: python:3.7.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      caches:
        - pip
      script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
        - pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
        - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    - step:
      script:
        - python3 -m unittest discover -vp 'Test*.py'
```

The file requirements.txt is the following:

```
tensorflow==2.4.1
Keras==2.4.3
pandas==1.1.3
requests==2.24.0
matplotlib==3.3.2
numpy==1.19.2
```

numpy is present in the requirements but when it runs the unit tests, I get the following error:

```
  import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved the issue by generating a new requirements.txt within a virtual environment.
Then I've replaced the bitbucket-pipelines.yml with one of the templates provided by Atlassian at [this link](https://bitbucket-pipelines.prod.public.atl-paas.net/validator):

```
#  Template python-build

#  This template allows you to validate your python code.
#  The workflow allows running tests and code linting on the default branch.

image: python:3.8

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: Test
          caches:
            - pip
          script:
            - if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
            - pip install pytest
            - pytest -v tests/* --junitxml=test-reports/report.xml
```

More information here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the first step you install the dependencies with pip3, which will not be available in the next step becauses it's a different container. If you want to keep your dependencies you must cache them as follows:

```
image: python:buster
definitions:
  caches:
    pip3: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

The path is variable depending on the version of python you have, you can run the command `pip3 show <dependency>` in the pipeline to verify if is the right path.

[command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpPMt.png)

And you need to add the cache to the step who needs the dependencies, in your case, the second step:

```
image: python:3.7.3
definitions:
  caches:
    pip3: <path>
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      name: First step
      caches:
        - pip3
      script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
        - pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
        - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    - step:
      name: Second step
      caches:
        - pip3
      script:
        - python3 -m unittest discover -vp 'Test*.py'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. I will post my solution in a different answer